# How to add subdomains to my onion site

Tags: darknet

So I have a onion website and I start it by using `php -S 127.0.0.1:8080` and `sudo -u debian-tor tor` to start the website. I wonder if there is any solution to add a subdomain like ***[www.mysubdomain.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.onion](http://www.mysubdomain.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.onion)*** and not just one, but many different subdomains.

I have seen many websites in the Tor network with subdomains, and I want that and I'm open to any possible solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that **directly**: Tor does not support this. It seems to be lame from the classical point of view, but keep in mind what the onion domain is - it's a derivative of the key data, so there can be only one, you know ;)